# Implementing Dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to implement dictonary of lists as follows:

```
hash_dict={
        'session':{'Hash_path':[],'Hex_hash':[]},
        'meta':{'Hash_path':[],'Hex_hash':[]},
        'packet':{'Hash_path':[],'Hex_hash':[]}
    }
```

I have a list hash_list which contains lot of data but I want three types of values :session,meta and packet and want the values in above dictionary as list.

Is this possible as I have defined above.
Any help is appreciated.

```
    for i in range(len(hash_list)):
        if 'sessiondb' in hash_list[i]:
            hash_dict['session']['Hash_path'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[0].split("=")[1])
            hash_dict['session']['Hex_hash'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[9].split("=")[1])
    for i in range(len(hash_list)):
        if 'metadb' in hash_list[i]:
            hash_dict['metadb']['Hash_path'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[0].split("=")[1])
            hash_dict['metadb']['Hex_hash'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[9].split("=")[1])
    for i in range(len(hash_list)):
        if 'packetdb' in hash_list[i]:
            hash_dict['packetdb']['Hash_path'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[0].split("=")[1])
            hash_dict['packetdb']['Hex_hash'][i].append(hash_list[i].split(" ")[9].split("=")[1])
```

the above code shows the values which I want in Dictionary as list defined above.
I tried but I am getting the error: "list index out of range"

Thanx in advance.

Comment: post an example of `hash_list`

Comment: drop the `[i]` in `hash_dict['session']['Hash_path'][i].append` It has nothing to do here.

Comment: What exactly is contained in `hash_list`? Your parsing of the contained strings is somewhat ineffective and contains a lot of repetition, and you are appending lists to each. It'd help if you showed some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the dictionary first:

```
hash_dict = {
    'session': {'Hash_path': [], 'Hex_hash': []},
    'meta':    {'Hash_path': [], 'Hex_hash': []},
    'packet':  {'Hash_path': [], 'Hex_hash': []}
}
```

and loop over your list, directly, once:

```
for entry in hash_list:
    elems = entry.split()
    path = elems[0].split('=', 1)[-1]
    hash = elems[9].split('=', 1)[-1]

    if 'sessiondb' in entry:
        hash_dict['session']['Hash_path'].append(path)
        hash_dict['session']['Hex_path'].append(hash)

    if 'metadb' in entry:
        hash_dict['meta']['Hash_path'].append(path)
        hash_dict['meta']['Hex_path'].append(hash)

    if 'packetdb' in entry:
        hash_dict['packet']['Hash_path'].append(path)
        hash_dict['packet']['Hex_path'].append(hash)
```

which assumes that all three options are possible *per entry*.

This can most likely be cleaned up further if we knew what your `hash_list` data typically looks like.